# Programa para validar si está correcta la entrada de una fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa usando if

Tags: python, date, validación

*Hola para todos , me han solicitado hacer un programa que retorne un valor booleano indicando si el formato de ingresado por el usuario está bien.

Debe ser en formato `DD/MM/AAAA`, me dan esta función para asignarle instrucciones*

```
def formatoFechaCorrecto(fecha):
    return
```

**Código** el cual muestra errores:

```
def formatoFechaCorrecto(fecha):
  if fecha[2]!="/":
    return False
  if fecha[5]!="/":
    dia=int(fecha[:2])
    if dia > 31:``
      return False
    mes=int(fecha[3:5])
    if mes >12:
      return False
      ano=int(fecha[6:])
      if ano > 2021 or ano <1900:
        return False
    return True

#llamar la función
fecha=int(input("Escribe la fecha dd/mm/aaaa: "))
fecha=formatoFechaCorrecto(fecha)
print (fecha)
```

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no se hacen tareas.

Comment: Deberías adjuntar lo que has intentado.

Comment: @ZaninBlue Edita la pregunta con el código.

Comment: En serio, no cuesta nada -> https://www.google.com/search?q=validar+formato+fecha+python&oq=validar+formato+fecha+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.2214j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @omaza1990 gracias por modificar la pregunta, es la primera vez que uso esta página , perdón si los incomodé

Comment: No incomodaste a nadie, tranquilo c: Esta linea `int(input("Escribe la fecha dd/mm/aaaa: "))` debería darte un error por que una cadena cuyo formato es "xx/xx/xxxx" no puede ser interpretada como entero. Por ejemplo 12/12/2020 no se puede convertir en entero. La solución es quitar el int de `int(input("Escribe la fecha dd/mm/aaaa: "))`.

Comment: En conclusión, una fecha no puede ser interpretada como un número.

Comment: Podrías agregar el mensaje de error en la pregunta por favor? Así podemos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Sobre tus disculpas, pasa que hay mucha gente que va a esta pagina con la esperanza de que les resolvamos las tareas, lo cual no es bien recibido. Ahora sabemos que no es esa tu intención c:

Comment: @DanteS. tienes razón ya funcionó gracias :D, pero ahora tengo otro problema jaja , al momento de ingresar los datos si lo escribo sin el formato DD/MM/AAAA esta bien porque retorna False, pero si lo escribo con el formato adecuado me retorna None y necesito que retorne True, ¿ Que debo hacer para especificar eso?

Comment: Tu código y el de la pregunta es el mismo? Por que tu código en la pregunta tiene problemas de identación. Por ejemplo el `return True` de tu función está dentro de este condicional `if fecha[5]!="/": ` lo que hace que tu función solo retorne True cuando el sexto caracter NO es "/".

Comment: Y ese es solo uno de los problemas de identación que tiene tu código...

Comment: Por cierto, de nada :D

Comment: Estuve viendo tu código, y tiene un fallo logico. Cuando el sexto caracter no es "/" o sea la fecha no tiene el formato correcto, es cuando empiesas a ver si el año es correcto, si el dia es correcto, etc... No debería retornar False cuando ese condicional se cumple?

Comment: Voy a darte una respuesta con todas las correcciones necesarias.

Comment: @DanteS. ya revisé la identación y efectivamente estaba mal, la compuse poniendo el `return True` alineado con la primera condición de la fecha , pero tienes razon con eso solo arreglé el de el día

Comment: @DanteS. es decir, si escribo mal a proposito el formato en la parte de DD retorna False, pero en los demás faltantes MM, AAAA retorna true,¿debería hacer un if y else aparte para cada variable( dia, mes , año) ?

Comment: @DanteS. esta bien ,eres muy amable

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido Zanin! c:

#### Código corregido

Aquí abajo te dejo el código con los fallos lógicos solucionados con cada solución explicada:

```
def formatoFechaCorrecto(fecha):
    # Si el tercer caracter no es igual a "/" y tampoco el quinto caracter, entonces la fecha no es valida y retornamos False.
    if fecha[2]!="/" or fecha[5]!="/":
        return False

    # Ahora que sabemos que la fecha tiene un formato valido, podemos evaluar si es correcto el dia, el mes y el año.

    dia=int(fecha[:2])
    if dia > 31:
        return False

    mes=int(fecha[3:5])
    if mes >12:
        return False

    ano=int(fecha[6:])
    if ano > 2021 or ano <1900:
        return False

    return True

# Quito el int de input ya que la fecha no puede ser interpretada como un entero.
fecha=input("Escribe la fecha dd/mm/aaaa: ")
fecha=formatoFechaCorrecto(fecha)
print (fecha)
```

#### Algunos aspectos que creo que deberías de tener en cuenta.

No se que si estos aspectos le van a importar o no a tu profesor, ni si tu curso está tan avanzado, pero ante la duda te los resalto para que tengas en cuenta.

- Que pasaría si el usuario ingresa una fecha cuyos día, mes o año tienen letras. Por ejemplo 1a/1b/202c? Tu función validadora mandaría un error de Python diciendo que alguno de estos no se pueden convertir en número.
- No todos los meses tienen 31 dias. Algunos tienen menos. Tu validación mostraría como valida la fecha "31/02/2020", a pesar de que febrero no tiene esa cantidad de dias nunca. Además, ten en cuenta el efecto que tiene el año bisiesto en la cantidad de dias de febrero.
- Quizá haya un motivo por el que pusiste este limite, pero no se cual es así que agrego este punto aquí por las dudas. El año de la fecha no tiene por que estar entre 2021 y 1900. La fecha "12/12/1000" y "12/12/2222" son validas. Al menos en circunstancias normales. Quiza tu profesor te haya dicho que pongas ese limite?

Comment: El primer `and` que has puesto debería ser un `or`, con que uno de los dos no cumpla ya no tiene el formato.

Comment: Cierto, no lo había pensado, gracias Adrian! c: